# pyqt print to pdf page breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a python code like this which converts url to pdf

```
 import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer, QSizeF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageLayout, QPageSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import argparse



def _fullScreenRequested(request):
    request.accept()
    loader.showFullScreen()

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Just an example", formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("--url", help="Type url")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    config = vars(args)
    url = config['url']


    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    loader.setZoomFactor(1)
    layout = QPageLayout()
    layout.setPageSize(QPageSize(QSizeF(13, 20), QPageSize.Unit.Inch, "4x6 in page", QPageSize.SizeMatchPolicy.ExactMatch))
    layout.setOrientation(QPageLayout.Portrait)
    loader.load(QUrl(url))
    loader.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(lambda *args: QApplication.exit())

    def emit_pdf(finished):
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: loader.page().printToPdf("test.pdf", pageLayout=layout))

    loader.loadFinished.connect(emit_pdf)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to add page breaks to that pdf using my python code

mainly these two

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after

is it possible to add page breaks in my python code ?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26681-How-to-add-page-break-when-printe-a-webview-to-PDF-format) it seems that it should work. Are you sure that you properly used the CSS syntax?

Comment: @musicamante are u suggesting we should add css to the website loaded here loader.load(QUrl(url)) ??
I'm asking if we can manipulate that using python code above ?

Comment: QWebEnginePage (and the printing function) can only do what the page source does: if the source document (or computed result) doesn't include the CSS page break properties, you have to set them. So, what you should ask yourself is: does that page use those properties? If it does, then the page breaks should be respected (and if they are not, please provide the links to those pages). Otherwise, you have to add those breaks on your own. QWebEnginePage is an interface to the resulting web page, if that page doesn't support something you need, then you need to manipulate it.